# Solving an optimization problem with lower computational complexity

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, geometric-programming

Given $$n, C, r_i, p_i, \quad∀ i={1,2,...,n} $$ I want to solve this optimization problem:
$$maximize \quad f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n {{(x_i/r_i)}^{p_i}} $$
$$s.t \quad {(x_i/r_i)≤1}, \quad {(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}/C ≤1$$
where 
$$0≤p_i≤1 \quad\quad,   \sum_{i=0}^n p_i =1\quad \quad\quad, ∀x_i,r_i∈R,\quad x_i,r_i>0,\quad C>0 $$ 
To solve this problem, I use primal-dual interior-point method. I don't need accuracy more than 3 digits. But, I need to use a way to solve it much faster. I wonder if I can approximate this problem to another one that can be solved faster or I can use another way to solve it. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please tell us what software you tried to use to solve this problem and something about how it failed.  What is the size of your problem, $n$?  Are you willing to make particular values, of $n$,$C$, $r$, $p$ available?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. n can be 2, and can be increased to 100 or even 1000. I give this optimization problem in the GP form to the CVX, in Matlab. It takes about 250 ms to be solved in my platform with just n=2.  This time is alot in my case as I am using results of this optimization problem in a bigger problem that has time constraint in order of 20 ms (at most), in the same platform. in case of n=2 the samples can be:  $$ p_1=0.44, p_2=0.66, C=100, r_1=98, r_2=65 $$

Comment: It's important to realize that CVX is not fast, and is not intended to be fast. CVX is designed to be easy to use and readable, so that you can test out ideas quickly. If you need to solve an optimization problem very fast, you should use some other software, perhaps Mosek or something, or perhaps your own custom solver. Boyd has given talks about solving small optimization problems extremely fast, like on the order of milliseconds. See this paper for example: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/rt_cvx_opt.html

Comment: Note that the GP mode in CVX uses a successive approximation scheme because the standard solvers in CVX don't support the exponential cone.  So, you've got significant overhead both in terms of CVX's transformation of the GP problem and in terms of this successive approximation scheme.  Using ecos directly as an exponential cone solver should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

By using the transformation $y_{i}=\log(x_{i})$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$, and maximizing the logarithm of the original objective and dropping constant terms, you end up with the problem

$\max \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} y_{i}$

subject to

$y_{i} \leq \log(r_{i})$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$\mbox{logsumexp}(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{n}) \leq \log(C)$

This is an exponential cone programming problem that can be solved with the ECOS interior-point solver or the SCS first order solver.  You could also just hand it to a conventional nonlinear programming solver.

I went ahead and implemented this in MATLAB/ECOS.  For the $n=2$ case given in the question the solution time on my desktop machine was consistently about 10 ms.  For randomly generated problems with $n=100$, I loosened the optimality tolerances in ECOS a bit and got solutions good to about 4 digits in 25 ms or less.  This compares with about 1 second for these problems using CVX.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. n can be 2, and can be increased to 100 or even 1000. I give this optimization problem in the GP form to the CVX, in Matlab. It takes about 250 ms to be solved in my platform with just n=2.  This time is alot in my case as I am using results of this optimization problem in a bigger problem that has time constraint in order of 20 ms (at most), in the same platform. in case of n=2 the samples can be:  $$ p_1=0.34, p_2=0.66, C=100, r_1=98, r_2=65 $$

Comment: See updated answer with some computational results using ECOS vs. CVX.  The MATLAB version of ECOS comes close to meeting your performance requirement.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I changed the solver to ECOS, and now the solution time is  about 40 ms, that is more than five times faster than before. But still your solution time seems much faster. I use ECOS in CVX by the command "cvx_solver ECOS" in Matlab. Can I know the details of your implementation including the CVX syntax of this optimization problem? Thank you!

Comment: I believe that CVX can only use the second order cone features of ECOS, not the exponential cone.  Thus I think it is probably still doing the iterative refinement- you should check the output to make sure.  My MATLAB code reformulates the problem as an exponential cone problem and calls ECOS directly.  Also, my desktop machine might just be a bit faster than your machine (the difference is now 40 ms vs. 20-25 ms for $n=100$.)

Comment: I can confirm that even with "cvx_solver ecos", CVX 2.1 uses the successive approximation technique rather than directly using the exponential cone feature of ecos.  The documentation for CVX 3.0 beta says that it still uses the successive approximation technique with ecos rather than using ecos's exponential cone feature.